# Cannot run load tests because Visual Studio opens them with an xml editor

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

Usually, when I open a `.loadtest` file in Visual Studio, the file is being opened with a graphic UI which allows me, among other things, to run the load tests. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on a different machine now and the loadtest file is being opened with an xml editor. How do I make Visual Studio open the file with the load tests GUI?

I can't find any load test GUI option when right clicking the file and choosing "open with".

Comment: LoadTests come with the Ultimate SKU of Visual Studio, are you certain  you have the right version of Visual Studio installed? And in the properties window, is the correct compiler action chosen?

Answer (score 7):

You can revert back it to UI from xml.

Right Click on .loadtest file in viual studio project

Click on OpenWith Option

Choose Load Test Editor(Default)

Click on OK

It will revert back .loadtest xml view to UI view.

Comment: Hi, what if the "Load Test Editor" option is not displayed? - it's displayed in one of my computers but not in the other one....

Comment: Nevermind, I just installed the enterprise edition and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

The following blog article appears to be useful:

http://www.devcurry.com/2010/05/restore-file-associations-in-visual.html#.UmBoDbOBCgY

Short version: You can restore Visual Studio file associations by opening Visual Studio 2010 and going to Tools->Options->Environment->General and clicking the Restore File Associations button.

You will probably have to run Visual Studio as an administrator for these settings to take effect properly. (Right click Visual Studio icon, click Run As Administrator).

As noted above, if you have a lower SKU of Visual Studio 2010 installed than Ultimate, it may not associate this file type.